# Removing a Coordinate Singularity of a 2D metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, geodesics

While trying to find the null geodesics of the metric

$$
ds^2 = (r^2 - 1)dt^2 - (drdt + dtdr)
$$

gives $$\frac{dt}{dr} = \frac{2}{r^2-1}$$ which is singular at $r=1$. However, we know that this is a coordinate singularity because the curvature (Ricci) scalar is independent of $r$, $$\mathcal{R} = 2$$

So, how can I get the correct null geodesics? Or what is the coordinate transformation needed here?

Answer (score 8):

Your equation is just
$$\frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}(r^2-1) \implies \frac{dr}{r^2-1} = \frac{dt}{2}$$

This expression can readily be integrated to yield a non-singular $r(t)$.  To more specifically address your concern, if you set $r=1$ then the null geodesics are simply given by $r(t)=1$, since $\mathrm dr/\mathrm dt=0$.

Comment: In this problem, I am interested in the time as a function of the coordinate, i.e. t(r). So, I want to know the function t(r) = ln((1-r)/(1+r)).

Comment: @AhmadHaithamIbrahim That’s fine, unless $r=1$ in which case the geodesic is a curve of constant $r$. Clearly in such a case you cannot find a function $t(r)$, but that doesn’t mean anything is singular. It’s the same reason you can’t write the line $x=0$ in the form $y=f(x)$ for some function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answer your question ?
the metric from your line element is:

$$G= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} {r}^{2}-1&-1\\ -1&0
\end {array} \right]
$$

the determinate of the metric is  $~\text{det}(G)=-1~$ hence the metric is not singular at the entire space.

---

we are looking for the transformation matrix $~\mathbf{T}~$ that fulfilled  this matrix equation
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{T^T}\,\mathbf G\,\mathbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}
                                       1 & 0 \\
                                       0 & -1 \\
                                     \end{bmatrix}\quad (1)\quad
\text{4 equations for the unknowns $~T_i~,~i=1..4~$ }  \\                                   
&\text{solution}\\
&\mathbf{T}= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&1\\ \frac 12\,{r}^{2}-1&\frac 12
\,{r}^{2}\end {array} \right]\\\\
&\text{hence with}\\
&\begin{bmatrix}
   dt \\
   dr \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{T}
 \begin{bmatrix}
   d\tau \\
   du \\
 \end{bmatrix}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\left( {r}^{2}-1 \right) {{\it dt}}^{2}-2\,{\it dt}\,{\it dr}\mapsto
d\tau^2-du^2                            
\end{align*}

Comment: That is right. The problem is that I am trying to solve for $r$.

Let $\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{d\tau}$, where $\tau$ is the proper time, the Lagrangian looks like:

$L = (r^2-1)\dot{t}^2 - 2 \dot{r} \dot{t}$

Solving for Euler-Lagrange equations, we have 

For the time coordinate, we get
$$
\dot{t} = \frac{E+\dot{r}}{r^2-1}
$$

This last equation diverges when $r=1$. Also, if we substitute in the Lagrangian, we get

$$
L = (E-\dot{r})\dot{t} = \frac{E^2 - \dot{r}^2}{r^2-1}
$$
Now, the Lagrangian also diverges at $r=1$. So, I am trying to find a coordinate transformation.

Comment: you mean some think like this ?
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{T^T}\,\mathbf G\,\mathbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}
                                       1 & 0 \\
                                       0 & -1 \\
                                     \end{bmatrix}\\
&\text{where}\\
&\mathbf{T}= \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&1\\ \frac 12\,{r}^{2}-1&\frac 12
\,{r}^{2}\end {array} \right]\quad\Rightarrow\\
&\left( {r}^{2}-1 \right) {{\it dt}}^{2}-2\,{\it dt}\,{\it dr}\mapsto
d\tau^2-du^2                                     
\end{align*}

Comment: I do not really understand this transformation, could you please elaborate?
I mean what are the functions 
$$u(r, t)$$
and
$$\tau (r, t)$$
?

Comment: @AhmadHaithamIbrahim i put more information in my answer

Comment: Thanks. I got your point, but the problem is that the Ricci scalar is no longer the same value. I mean for 
$$ds^2 = d\tau^2 - du^2$$
the Ricci scalar value is 
$$\mathcal{R} = 0$$
which means the coordinate transformation changed the spacetime curvature. So, can we consider this a valid coordinate transformation? Physics (here curvature) should be invariant under coordinate transformation, right?

Comment: This is because it is local transformation

Comment: Yes. I gottcha you. Is there any kind of global transformation that we may use instead? Also, I am asking all of these questions to solve the problem of divergence at $r=1$. I am looking for the final differential equation, because when you solve for the Lagrangian given in the question above, we get the following DEQ

$$\frac{d^2 r}{d\tau^2} = \frac{r}{r^2 -1}(\dot{r}^2 + E^2)$$

Which is still divergent at $r=1$, even though we know that this is not physics ($\mathcal{R} = 1$).

Comment: this is the first integral $~\dot t\,(r^2-1)+\dot r=E~$ solve it for $~\dot r~$ and substitute to the EOM's  is there any  singularly ?

\begin{align*}
  &{\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}t \left( \tau
 \right) +r \left( \tau \right)  \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}t \left(
\tau \right)  \right) ^{2}=0\\& {\frac {d^{2}}{d{
\tau}^{2}}}r \left( \tau \right)-r \left( \tau \right)
 \left(  \left( r \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}-1 \right)  \left(
{\frac {d}{d\tau}}t \left( \tau \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\,r \left( \tau
 \right) E{\frac {d}{d\tau}}t \left( \tau \right)  =0
\end{align*}